# Do standard rectangle USB to Thunderbolt 2 cables exist?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

Do standard rectangle USB to Thunderbolt 2 cables exist?
I want to use my Thunderbolt 2 ports to connect a standard USB hub.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean 'do they exist'?

Comment: You appear to have your requirements backwards, which will be why you can't find one. You need Thunderbolt to USB.

Comment: Since I am a programmer I know how to use google thanks. Thunderbolt 2 <--> standard USB |___|

Comment: @AnExistingPerson Thanks for offering a suggestion. Can you review the [code of conduct](https://apple.stackexchange.com/conduct) on how we prefer people to make a "search the internet" comment or better a full answer explaining how one might search for the answer in detail.

Comment: @Tetsujin no I need a cable that sends data both ways.

Comment: Of course - but the adaptor needs to be Thunderbolt **to** USB, as in bmike's example below. It cannot be done the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbolt 2 is an active connector so even though USB is able to be embedded in the data lines, you would need a full thunderbolt chip to establish that link.

Kanex makes amazingly reliable and fairly priced hardware in my experience:

-[https://www.amazon.com/Kanex-Thunderbolt-eSATA-plus-Adapter/dp/B00LOLBBQQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LOLBBQQ)

Also, look for used or fire sale full docks, since they are much less expensive now that Thunderbolt3 / USB 4 is the new hotness for adapters and docks - the older ones might be available as people upgrade to the latest.